# Hot to get x(i) array using the previous values x(i-1) in Ax=b within the for loop in python

Tags: python-3.7

I have a issue with my code and I need help is welcome.

I create an array from Excel file ([here](https://uapt33090-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ruifoliveira_ua_pt/EaPuyImw1ZpImFFxOWwdfoQBFeytYObThDYTLb1O-DyjMQ?e=fMUzey)). This data giving in the first line are the initial conditions of the system. x(i) should be my C1, C2 and C3 for each line.

I solve x in Ax=b, creating the vector x(i) for each step using the previous calculated value, instead of taking the previous value from the excel file. (I'm using Spider)

I want to solve x taking into account the x(i-1) calculated previously.

Someone can give me some instruction to deal with this issue?
Thank you in advance.

```
# Import data from Excel file:
data = pd.read_excel('3zones_DataObserved_1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Constant variables:
v1 = 30
v2 = 35
v3 = 30
dt = 5

# Solving x in Ax=b:

dataarray = data.to_numpy()
countr = 1
for i in range(1,len(dataarray)):
    # matrix A 3x3
    A = np.array([[v1/dt+dataarray[i][4]/2, -dataarray[i][4]/2, -dataarray[i][4]],
                  [-dataarray[i][5]/2, v2/dt+dataarray[i][5]/2, -dataarray[i][5]/2],
                  [-dataarray[i][6]/2, -dataarray[i][6]/2, v3/dt+dataarray[i][6]/2]])
   # vector A 3x1
    b = np.array([[v1*dataarray[i-1][3]/dt-dataarray[i-1][4]*dataarray[i-1][0]/2+dataarray[i][7]/2],
                  [v2*dataarray[i-1][3]/dt-dataarray[i-1][5]*dataarray[i-1][1]/2+dataarray[i][8]/2],
                  [v3*dataarray[i-1][3]/dt-dataarray[i-1][6]*dataarray[i-1][2]/2+dataarray[i][9]/2]])
    # vector A 3x1
    x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)

    print ("Ite ",countr,":",x[0],x[1],x[2])
    countr += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If altering `dataarray` is not a concern, instead of:

```
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

you could:

```
x = dataarray[i][:3] = np.linalg.solve(A,b).flat
```

Note: `.flat` is important to get `[###,###,###]` instead of `array([[###],[###],[###]])`

Comment: It works, for this use I change dataarray, but in other works that i'm facing I cannot. Maybe I can use the method of @g_bor(next comment). But still some doubts how to reach a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to access the previously calculated value of x. One way to do that would be to move the definition of x before the for loop. Then after the assignment in the loop body, you have the old x values in x when entring the loop again.

Comment: I see the point, however something I'm making wrong.
Could you give me some little example?
I tried this:

x1 = []
Loop:
   A = ...
   b = ...
   x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
print(x)

Comment: For this case you need three things: __(1)__ initialize `x` before the loop with `x = dataarray[0][:3]`  __(2)__ replace the instances of `dataarray[i-1][0]`, `dataarray[i-1][1]`, and `dataarray[i-1][2]` with `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` when calculating `b`  __(3)__ update `x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)` to `x = np.linalg.solve(A,b).flat`.

Comment: This part I understood and it is working well. Thank's. However, if I want in the step 1), change the columns 4, 6 and 8 (no sequence columns) instead of the first three columns("[:3]"). How I can initialize x in this new approach?

Comment: you could do x[0]=dataarray[0][4]... is this what you mean?